# CloudFiles - Rackspace connection error c#

Tags: c#, connection, rackspace, unauthorized, cloudfiles

I am trying to connect to rackspace using their api and passing my username and api key but i get this error :

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

here is my code :

```
        UserCredentials userCreds = new UserCredentials("myusername", "myapikey");
        Connection connection = new Connection(userCreds);
```

I have followed this tutorial :

```
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Sample_CSharp_Application
```

have asked their support and they say we can connect with same key using curl...and they couldnt provide much help.

anyone has any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for anyone else who got same problem here i found the solution, you basically need to include the api uri :

http://blog.chmouel.com/2011/01/04/how-to-use-the-rackspace-cloud-uk-api/

Answer (score 3):

Your sample works but I was looking for a direct way, without the wrapper. This seems to work as well, and uses direct restful access to the Rackspace API.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

```
        string url = "https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-User:" + userName);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Key:" + apiKey);
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            string[] keys = response.Headers.AllKeys;

            foreach (var k in keys)
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers[k]);
        }
```